# How can I extract htaccess file

Tags: php, web

which including images of a website?
I am trying to get the information of the website, this file should contain all of the images..

Thanks!

Comment: .htaccess (HyperText Access)  file can be used to make the server behave in a certain way.
This file cannot store images data.

Comment: @Smartpal so what it means if writen on it Options +Indexes? thanks

Comment: It's Turn ON directory Indexes for specific folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is unclear, Let me describe what is `.htaccess` file?

1. `.htaccess` (HyperText Access) file is used to customise server configuration.
2. This file cannot store any files(Audios,Videos, Images etc) data.

Let's assume, you've `images` directory on your server which contains all of your image files, and you want to list and make publically available to download. Simply create `.htaccess` file in the directory and type `Options +Indexes` in it. When visitors visit directory (`images`) from browser it'll get image list.
Read more [here](http://www.htaccess-guide.com)

Comment: Thank you! now unserstood.. and If I want to add image to that directory, I should I do it?

Comment: @Ella If you own the site, Login to cpanel and use file manager to upload file to the directory or upload through FTP.